# Details of last ran cron job in Unix-like systems?

Tags: linux, logging, cron

I want to get the details of the last run cron job. If the job is interrupted due to some internal problems, I want to re-run the cron job.

Note: I don't have superuser privilege.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can see the date, time, user and command of previously executed cron jobs using:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

This will show *all* cron jobs. If you only wanted to see jobs run by a certain user, you would use something like this:

```
grep CRON.*\(root\) /var/log/syslog
```

**Note that cron logs at the start of a job** so you may want to have lengthy jobs keep their own completion logs; if the system went down halfway through a job, it would still be in the log!

*Edit:* If you don't have root access, you will have to keep your own job logs. This can be done simply by tacking the following onto the end of your job command:

```
&& date > /home/user/last_completed
```

The file `/home/user/last_completed` would always contain the last date and time the job completed. You would use `>>` instead of `>` if you wanted to append completion dates to the file.

You could also achieve the same by putting your command in a small bash or sh script and have cron execute that file.

```
#!/bin/bash
[command]
date > /home/user/last_completed
```

The crontab for this would be:

```
* * * * * bash /path/to/script.bash
```

Comment: Is there any way to see details with root  user privilege . Because I didn't have root privilege .

Comment: You would need to have your jobs keep their own completion log. Edited to show example.

Comment: Does this answer apply for cron jobs running as root as well as for those running as my local user?

Comment: @Richard - Yep, Cron logs jobs for all users in syslog (at least under Debian): `sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog` to see them, or replace `root` with the user you want to see jobs from in the second command in my answer.

Comment: no `syslog` path on my CentOS, but it directly in `/var/log/cron` file instead

Answer (score 13):

`/var/log/cron` contains cron job logs. But you need a root privilege to see.

Comment: I don't see any file or directory with the name *cron* on the path */var/log/*

Comment: I think answers should explicitly specify what distribution they are related to!!!

Comment: On *CentOS*, *Redhat* and *Amazon Linux* cron logs are written to `/var/log/cron`. Source: https://cronitor.io/cron-reference/where-are-cron-logs-stored

Answer (score 6):

CentOs,
`sudo grep CRON /var/log/cron`

Comment: or even better `sudo grep CRON /var/log/cron | grep \(user\)`